# Getting accessible fields of a Salesforce object using REST API

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I have a SOSL query where I search for an email address in both Contact and Lead SObject. I instruct the query to return some fields like FirstName, MobilePhone, etc., Now, if my SF org does not have the MobilePhone field visibility to true, the query returns "Invalid Column MobilePhone".

Is there a way where I can fetch the available fields for a given object *using the Force.com REST API* before firing my query?

My SOSL query is

```
FIND {test@er.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Phone, Id, Department, Email, isDeleted, Name, MailingCity, Title ), Lead(Id, City, Company, Country, Name, MobilePhone, Phone, State, Status, Street, Title)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find the information you need using the [SObject Describe functionality](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_describe.htm) or the REST API equivalent, the /services/data/v24.0/sobject/[SObject]/describe [REST API Describe call](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_describe.htm). If a field such as MobilePhone is not in the child "fields" list returned by the REST describe call, then it is not accessible. So if you have a list of fields you would like to return, you should check to see if they are returned in the "fields" list, and not include them in your SOSL query if they are not there.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried the "describe" rest resource. As you mentioned, it does not return the hidden fields. Is there any other way to fetch all the fields of an object in SF.

Comment: the describe resource is what you want, it has the list of available fields, you an cull your list of fields in the query based on that.

Comment: Aravind, superfell is correct --- if a given field you'd like to query on is not returned in the "fields" property of a given SObject's REST API describe call, then that field is not accessible to the running user, so you should not include it in your SOSL query.